# Problem to set constraints programatically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I want put a `UISegmentedControl` in header of `UITableView` that use all horizontal space.

This is like this:

[image]

I want to use all space so I want set constraints. I tried this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            if section == 0 {
                let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height:
                    UITableViewAutomaticDimension))
                headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: segmentedControl, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            var constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: segmentedControl, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraint,constraint2])
            headerView.addSubview(segmentedControl)

            return headerView
        }
    }
```

But the follow erro occurs:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000a7cbc0 "UISegmentedControl:0x7fc4cf480b20.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000a7c7c0 "UIView:0x7fc4cf5b3f70.leading"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: You are setting the constraints before adding the segmentedControl to the view. You should first add it to the view and then set it's constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `segmentedControl` to `headerView` before activating the constraints

```
var constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: segmentedControl, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
var constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: segmentedControl, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
headerView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraint,constraint2])
```

Comment: This works. I will accept. But when I put `10` for example, the trailling keeping outside window. https://imgur.com/PicTY0J. `let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: segmentedControl, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)`

Comment: max X of segment  = max X of header + 10  , so if you need it inside view it should be -10 this is how the constraint is translated eventually as trailing  = max X